# Google based webform and excel data base

Tags: web-applications

I want to create a simple web based form that enables the user

- to enter a lost and found entry consisting of `Date`, `Time`, `Item
  description`.
- I want the data to be stored in a spreadsheet somewhere.
- I want the user to have a web based way to browse and search the
  data , be it on some google spreadsheet like object or some webpage
  like object
- Add `Date of pickup` entry to an existing record once it is picked
  up.

I dont know how to program in any language (just mathematica) but I am smart and I can mimic something simple. This doesn't have to be very sharp or professional. Just spartan and functional.

I have seen people use google forms to add game scores and view results, rankings etc on google spreadsheet. I have not seen any functionality that enables users modify existing entries.

Any advice on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use PHP5.1+  with SQLite as the database OR "php simplexml" as a database.  You can use a simple "PHP contact form" as a template for your project and then hack it to work like you need it.   Also, you can use a PHP ODBC driver to connect to a actual spreadsheet in MS Office.

Start with [this link](http://www.easyphp.org/).

Also, I found a open source AJAX/PHP spreadsheet,  [is this one](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSpreadsheet/).

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Forms and Google Docs Spreadsheet sounds reasonable.  This google blog post should help you get started: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/02/add-data-to-google-spreadsheets-using.html